# Magento - Update Prices Script - Multiple Stores

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to update some (but not all ) prices from one store to another. For example one line of shirts should be 1.2 times the price in the second store

I would like to update some groups of items only, based on entity label but am struggling to pull all the data from magento (asside what i can get out in the code below). The bits I am missing are price and entity label. I know what tables they live in but not sure the correct magento syntax to access them eg Mage::getModel('catalog/product') and I am trying to achieve this using Magento friendly code and not queries

Using enterprise 1.11, not looking at buying a plugin at this stage, any advice greatly appreciated

```
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID); #important
$product_id = '8782';
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
         ->load($product_id);
        echo "Collection: " . $collection->getName();
        echo "<br>";
        echo "Attribute Set: " . $collection->getAttributeSetId() . " SKU: " . $collection->getSku();
        echo "<br>"; 
        echo "Entity ID: " . $collection->getEntity_id() . " Product Type (Attribute Label): " . $collection->getProducttype();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just clarifying:

In the sample you've shown, the $collection object isn't really a "collection".
It's an instance of one 'catalog/product' object.

To modify the price of one catalog/product object, you'd be looking at doing something like this:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$product->setPrice($product->getPrice() * 1.2)
        ->save();
```

If you want to do this over a bunch of products, you'll probably want to use a collection of
'catalog/product' objects, and apply some attribute filters (which boils down to adding 
WHERE clauses to the eventually generated SQL). ([Here's one summary](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento) of the magento collection query 
syntax.)

I'm not sure what you mean by "entity label".  Is that a custom attribute you've attached to your products?

A general example, applying this price change to all products with a certain SKU:

```
$product_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                                                       ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('like' => 'FOO01-%'));

foreach($product_collection as $product) {

    $new_price = calcNewPrice($product->getPrice());
    $product->setPrice($new_price)
            ->save(); 

}
```

Where, if you're going across stores for price calcs, "calcNewPrice" might look something like this:

```
function calcNewPrice($product) {
    $other_store_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($other_store_id)
                                                            ->load($product->getId());
    if ($other_store_product) {
        return $other_store_product->getPrice() * 1.2;
    }
    // else ???
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, got me 3 steps closer. I meant Attribute Label, not entity, sorry, it is found in the back end under Catalog/Attributes/manage attributes.
It lives under the table eav_attribute_option_value and the heading of value, If I can access that data I can use it as a grouping to edit prices
Thanks so much for your help so far

Comment: Found the 2 values I was looking for after trawling the forums, turns out this returns the correct values
    echo "Attribute Text: " . $collection->getAttributeText('producttype') . " Option ID: " . $collection->getData('producttype');
From here I hope to use getAttributeText to find groups of products, using the corresponding Option Id, match it with the store id in the catalog_product_index_eav table to get the entity_id and use those valuse to update the price in the catalog_product_entity_decimal table.
Anyone see any potential problems with this?

Comment: Is their any way to Update/Create quantity per website OR per store?